# Delegate not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol declared in a class

```
public protocol demoDelegate {
    func willShowdemoResult(DemoGraph: UIView)
}
```

Now I am calling this in the same class where the protocol is declared.

```
public class Demo:UIViewController {
public var delegate : demoDelegate!

//some code 

 self.delegate.willShowdemoResult(self.demoGraph())
}
```

where demo graph returns a UI graph

```
func demoGraph() -> UIView {
       //some code

        return demoGraphView
    }
```

I am getting an error that unexpectedly found nil while wrapping an optional value. I know the reason that I have not initialised the delegate. Can somebody guide me How to initialise the delegate here.

The function is being called in other class

```
class DemoResult: UIViewController, demoDelegate{
func willShowdemoResult(DemoGraph: UIView)
// some code
}
```

Please Help

Comment: Yes @FelixSFD I did that

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error, because `Demo.delegate` is `nil` when calling:

```
delegate.willShowdemoResult(self.demoGraph())
```

Before you make this call, make sure, that you have set the `delegate` property. I would recommend this right after initializing `Demo` or right after `DemoResult` got the address of the `Demo`-instance.

Let's assume, you have stored an instance of `Demo` in `DemoResult.demoVC`. Then you can set the `delegate` in `DemoResult` like this:

```
demoVC.delegate = self
```

---

BTW: It's better to use optional types to store delegates:

```
public var delegate: demoDelegate?
```

When `delegate` is optional, `delegate?.willShowdemoResult(self.demoGraph())` won't crash, if `delegate` has not been initialized yet.